# How to store Journey Report into a Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, journeybuilder, dataextensions, automationstudio

I have a Journey through which I am sending emails. I can extract the  journey report from Analytics Builder (as a Excel file). Where is this report data stored in SFMC ? Can I access this data in a Data extension?

or

Is there a way to send the data in this excel report to a Data extension?

Goal : I need the report data in a data extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about Journey Builder Email Send Summary report? You can configure the report, and save it as a report definition:

[image]

Once you've done so, you can schedule it to drop a csv file every 24 hours on your Enhanced FTP server:

[image]

I will suggest adding a subfolder for this, and create a File Location for the export/import to use.

When you have configured this export, you should set up an automation, which is runnning daily, and picks up this file in the dedicated file location, and imports it using an [Import Activity.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_use_an_import_activity.htm&type=5). This will place the content of the file in the data extension defined in the Import Activity.